# Delphi TDSAdminClient NotifyCallback with Apache module

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to NotifyCallback with DataSnap Apache Module REST Server. Below is my code for NotifyCallback:

```
procedure SendBuddyMessage(clientid, callbackid: string; Msg: TJSONValue);
var
  AClient: TDSAdminClient;
  aResponse: TJSONValue;
begin
  AClient := TDSAdminClient.Create
    (wscDataModule.ServerConnection.DBXConnection);
  try
  //aResponse := TJSONTrue.Create;
  AClient.NotifyCallback(clientid, callbackid, Msg, aResponse);
  finally
    AClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am getting following error:

```
Remote error: VAR and OUT arguments must match parameter type exactly
```

Why am getting this error? Is there any wrong with my code?
PS: I am doing this with Delphi Berlin Firemonkey Client.